# Unisharp Laravel-filemanager cant upload on laragon server

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laragon, unisharp-file-manager

when i try to upload an image with laragon server (***https://myblog.test***) it can't be uploaded

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orB5w.png)

log

> dropzone.min.js:1          POST https://myblog.test/filemanager/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

but when i try with (***php artisan serve***), the file uploads fine.

I didn't change anything in config/**filesystem.php**

how to fix it?

> UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\LfmUploadValidator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($file) must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, null given, called in C:\laragon\www\myblog\vendor\unisharp\laravel-filemanager\src\LfmPath.php on line 246

my **.env**

```
APP_URL=https://myblog.test/
```

my **routes**

```
Route::middleware(["auth"])->group(function () {

Bla Bla Bla

// Filemanager
Route::group(['prefix' => 'filemanager'], function () {
    Route::get('/index', [\App\Http\Controllers\FileManagerController::class, 'index'])->name('filemanager.index');
    \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});

Bla Bla Bla

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
upload_tmp_dir = c:\laragon\tmp
```

in php.ini

also I think you can see error in browser console.